# Download .csv attachments from Today

Tags: vba, outlook

I want to download 4 unique csv files that I receive daily. So I need to download these 4 automatically. As of now, I can download all csv files but I can't limit it to only today's date.

This is my current code.

```
Public Sub SaveAutoAttach(item As Outlook.MailItem)

Dim object_attachment As Outlook.Attachment

Dim saveFolder As String

saveFolder = "C:\Desktop\Automatic Outlook Downloads"
For Each object_attachment In item.Attachments


If InStr(object_attachment.DisplayName, ".csv") Then
'If Int(object_attachment.ReceivedTime) = Date Then
    object_attachment.SaveAsFile saveFolder & "\" & object_attachment.DisplayName

End If
'End If

Next


End Sub
```

Comment: Can you post hat you have done so far for us to help you?

Comment: Work with `MailItem.ReceivedTime property`

Comment: This is not your complete code; it a function that is called to save the attachments of a specific `MailItem`.  Some other code has selected that `MailItem`.  If you like 0m3r’s suggestion of using `ReceivedTime` to identify interesting `MailItem`s, I would put that code in the outer routine.

Comment: You are saving these attachments using `DisplayName` as the filename?  Are these `DisplayName`s unique or are you happy to overwrite earlier files?  If they are unique, you could use the existence of a file to indicate this `MailItem`’s attachments have already been saved.  Having said that, I would move the `MailItem` to another folder after I had saved the attachments, so it could never been found again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to answer my own question. Below is my modified code.

```
Public Sub SaveAutoAttach(item As Outlook.MailItem)
Dim olApp As Object
Dim olNS As Object
Dim myDate As Date
Dim olItems As Object
Dim olItem As Object
Dim olAttach As Object

On Error Resume Next
Set olApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
Err.Clear: On Error GoTo 0

If olApp Is Nothing Then
Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Flg = True
End If

Set olNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")

Set olItems = olNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Items

For Each olItem In olItems
    If olItem.ReceivedTime > Date Then
    On Error GoTo Finished
    Set olAttach = olItem.Attachments.item(1)
    Err.Clear: On Error GoTo 0
    If Not olAttach Is Nothing Then
    If olAttach.FileName Like "*.csv" Then

    On Error GoTo Finished
    olAttach.SaveAsFile "C:\Desktop\Automatic Outlook Downloads" & "\" & olAttach.FileName
    Set olAttach = Nothing
    Set olItem = Nothing
    End If
    End If
    End If
Next
```